# Optimized SQL Stored Proc is taking a long time to run in production

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have spent a lot of time optimizing a query for our DB Admin.  When I run it in our test server and our live server I get similar results.  However, once it is actually running in production with the query being utilized a lot it runs very poorly.

I could post code but the query is over 1400 lines and it would take a lot of time to obfuscate.  All data types match and I am using indices on my queries.  It is broken down into 58 temp tables.  When I test it using SQL Sentry I get it using 707 CPU cycles and 90,0007 reads and a time of 1.2 seconds to run a particular exec statement.  The same parameters in production last week used 10,831 CPU cycles, 2.9 million reads, and took 33.9 seconds to run.

My question is what could be making the optimizer run more cycles and reads in production than my one off tests?  Like I mentioned, I could post code if needed, but I am looking for answers that point me in a direction to troubleshoot such a discrepancy.  This particular procedure is run a lot during our Billing cycle so it is hitting the server hundreds of times a day, it will become thousands as we near the 15th of the month.

Thanks

ADDENDUM:
I know how to optimized queries as this is a regular part of my job duties.  As I stated in a comment, my test queries don't have large differences like this usually from actual production.  I don't know the SQL Server side of things and wondered if there was something I needed to be aware of that might affect my query when the server is under a heavier load.  This may be outside the scope of this forum, but I thought I would reach out for ideas from the community.

UPDATE:
I am still troubleshooting this, just replying to some of the comments.

The execution plans are the same between my one off tests and the production level executions.  I am testing in the same environment, on the same server as production.  This is a procedure for report data. The data returned, the records, and tables hit, are all the same.  I am testing using the same parameters that during production took astronomical amounts of time to process,  the difference between what I am doing and what happened during the production run is the load on the server.  Not all of production executions are taking a long time, the vast majority are within the thresholds of acceptable CPU and reads, when the outliers have such a large discrepancy it is 500 times the CPU and 150 times the reads of the average execution (even with the same parameters).

I have zero control over the server side of things.  I only can control how to code the proc.  I realize that my proc is large and without it, it is probably impossible to get a good answer on this forum.  I also realize that even with the code posted here I would not likely get a good answer due to the size of the procedure.

I was/am looking only for insights, directions of things to look at, using anecdotal evidence of issues other developers have overcome when dealing with similar problems.  Comments that state the size of my code is the reason why performance is in the toilet, and that code that size is rarely needed, are not helpful and quite frankly ignorant.  I am working with legacy c# code and a database that deals with millions of transactions for billing.  There are thousands of tables in dozens of interconnected databases with an ERD that would blow your mind, I am optimizing a nightmare.  That said, I am very good at it, and when myself and the database administrators are stumped as to why we see such stark numbers I thought I would widen my net and see if this larger community had any ideas.

Below is an image showing a report of the top 32 executions for this procedure in a 15 min window.  Even among the top 32 the numbers are not consistent.  The image below that shows all of the temp tables and main query that I just ran on the same server for #1 resource hog of the first image.  The rows are different temp tables with a sum at the bottom.  The sum shows 1.5 (1.492) seconds to run with 534 CPU and 92,045 reads. Contrast that with the 33.9 seconds, 10,831 CPU, and 2.9 million reads yesterday:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can we help optimise an SP when we don't have the DDL for the SP, or any related objects/indexes?

Comment: This is pure guessing... A system under pressure will behave differently. I'd monitor memory usage, page life expectation, disk latency and waits...

Comment: 1400 lines of t-sql and 58 temp tables and you are wondering why the performance is in the toilet? This isn't a task for an online forum. This is a task for a consultant. The reasons why could be nearly anything. Data size, fragmentation, stale statistics, the list could go on and on. You need to analyze the execution plan and figuring out where the bottlenecks are. And then probably consider rethinking this as very few times is that much code appropriate.

Comment: @SeanLange, I regularly code procs of this size and I get very good results, almost always.  I think Shnugo is sending me down the right path.  I think the issue is I generally don't see a discrepancy like this between my tests and actual production.  Sorry I have been working for 13 hours already today, I probably could have asked a better question.

Comment: You need to identify the statements taking longer and then investigate those. Sounds like you have jumped to a conclusion without any evidence. The larger number of reads would indicate either more data to process or a different execution plan. If it is a different execution plan this could be due to different SQL Server builds, different statistics, different environment (trace flags, database compat level or other options) or different H/W

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have evidence, I failed to mention it.  Yesterday was the wrong day to post.  Using server reports we are seeing that all executions are using the same plan and I am testing using the same parameters on the very same server as the executions that took a lot of resources to run, even while other production executions are taking place.